# MS SQL update column with auto incremented value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i recently imported some old data to a new SQL table and forgot to set the ID column to auto increment.

Now i have several "NULL"s in the column named ID.

Is there a way I can update all ID columns with an unique ID automatically?
sadly i have no clue how

After that I will be able to set the column to INT and Auto Increment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you give new ids to all the rows, or do you just want to fill in the null values?

Comment: Could you just drop the column and re-create it as identity? That will then number all the rows

Comment: @ZoharPeled I just want to fill in those rows where NULL is inside the column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using **Sequence Object** for Sql Server 2012

```
create Sequence Sq as int
minvalue 1
cycle;

update table set Column=NEXT VALUE FOR Sq where Column is null
```

Comment: How would that look like if i start with the value 2892 ? 
create Sequence SQ as int
minvalue 2892 ? Also i just want to affect the columns which have NULL inside them

Comment: If you use the Start Value With 2892 and Sequence value for int is exhausted then it will start with min int value (-2147483648.)sequence object Always start with it's min value so it is netter to use min value   @noa-dev

Comment: @noa-dev you can put Null condition for update Statement. Check my updated Answer

Comment: your Welcome @noa-dev

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to remove your old ID Column and add a new column ID with :

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD ID int IDENTITY
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a CTE (common table expression):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColA) AS RN,
            ID,
            ColA
    FROM    dbo.YourTable
)

UPDATE  cte 
SET     ID = RN
```

in this example the new id gets generated by ordering by `ColA` - but you can order by any column(s) you want.

Answer (score 2):

Without using of sequences and manual setting of starting value:

```
declare @MaxId int 

select @MaxId = max(id) from [TableA]

update [TableA] 
  set  @MaxId = id = @MaxId +1
where id is null
```

Works fine with all versions of SQL Server starting from 2008.
[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f4f5/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the current ID column is not important and the value assigned to the ID column is not relevant you could try the following:

1. Create a new int identity(1,1) column (this will automatically be populated with unique values by MS SQLServer)
2. Drop the old column
3. Optionally rename the newly created column to the old name.

A sample script could look like this:

```
// Create a new identity column    
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
      ADD NewID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
    GO

// Drop the old ID column
    ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
      DROP COLUMN OldID;
    GO

// Rename the new column from 'NewID' to 'OldID'
    EXEC sp_rename 'YourDataBase.YourTable.NewID', 'OldID', 'COLUMN'; 
    GO
```

This will not work when you have tables that have a relationship based on the values in the old ID column.

Comment: Thank you - my question has already been answered as seen below :)